# console message captured by onConsoleMessage is incomplete

Tags: java, android, webview, webchromeclient

I have `WebView` into which I'm loading a webpage, I have set the custom `WebChromeClient` to capture console logs but I've found it is incomplete comparing to the console in browser. The message returned by `cm.message()` doesnt contain all values passed to the console methods.

`console.log("Test");//Test`

will work but following will only display first param

`console.log("test", 1);//test - expected test  1`

is there any way to workaround it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An interesting bug!

You can wrap `console.log` in your own function that concatenates all the arguments into a single string. The JavaScript code for doing this is below:

```
(function() { 
    var oldLog = console.log;
    console.log = function() { 
        oldLog.call(console, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments).join(" "));
    }
})();
```

You can inject it into your page with `WebView.loadUrl('javascript:...')`, or `WebView.evaluateJavascript`.

Comment: `webView.loadUrl` should be called ASAP, I've placed it in the 'WebViewCLient#onPageStarted`.

Comment: Glad it works. I filed a bug against WebView: http://crbug.com/481013. Thanks for pointing out the issue!